# SSH config: How to automatically execute an interactive script locally before connection?

Tags: ssh, scripting, login-script

## Background:

I have a **local** script that needs to execute **locally** as a pre-requisite to making an ssh connection.

The script is already working, but currently users need to run the script, then make an ssh connection - two steps. **I would like that to happen in one step**.

Example script run, from the users perspective:

```
$ /scripts/generate-mfa-auth.sh
MFA Code: 12345
Configuring authorized_keys...
Success. You can now connect over ssh.

$ ssh me@host.local.example.com
```

## Goal / Problem:

I want this script to allow user input when triggered from ssh config.

For example, this below ssh config executes the script properly, but it **does not allow the user to interact** and the user is never shown any stdout of the script:

```
Match host bastion* exec "/scripts/generate-mfa-auth.sh"

Host bastion1.local.example.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-bastion-ssh-key

Host *local.example.com !bastion1.local.example.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-target-ssh-key
 ProxyCommand ssh ubuntu@bastion1.example.com -W %h:%p
```

## Question:

Is there any way to have this script work ***interactively*** when called from ssh config?

Comment: It sounds like you want an interactive script to provide MFA.  Your best option for a custom script will probably be something involving `pam_exec`.  I would encourage you to look at existing solutions like `pam_oath.so`/`oathtool`, and `google-authenticator`.

Comment: Thanks, yea MFA is already working and the script is already working. Currently users need to run the script, then make an ssh connection.... I would like that to happen in one step.

Comment: I didn't realize the script ran locally so my first comment is not relevant.  I added an answer that uses a fairly common pattern to change a command's behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with ssh configuration, but a fairly common solution is creating a script that is installed earlier in the `PATH`.  For example

```
install -m 0755 -o root -g root /dev/null /usr/local/bin/ssh
cat <<EOF > /usr/local/bin/ssh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "mfa prompt: " my_input
echo $my_input
/usr/bin/ssh "$@"
EOF
```

Other common suggestions involve creating an alias or a function to do the same thing.

**links**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399079/how-to-overwrite-a-bash-command
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915121/what-is-the-best-way-to-override-an-existing-shell-command
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783509/override-a-builtin-command-with-an-alias

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is no way to do this directly with ssh config `exec`